# Firebase Facebook OAuth Returns null On iOS Devices

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I've got a Firebase web application that uses the following method to authenticate user's via Facebook

```
let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('public_profile');
provider.addScope('user_location');
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
  .then(function(){
    return firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()
  })
  .then(function(result) {
      console.log('Logged in user ::: ', result.user);
  })
  .catch(err => { console.warn('An error occurred') })
})
```

However, all iOS devices and emulateors (except one, strangely) never retrieve the `user` object - instead I get `null`

- I've enabled Facebook as a Sign-in Provider in the Firebase console
- I've added my app's domain, facebook.com, and localhost as Authorized domains in the Firebase console
- I've tried repositioning `getRedirectResult()` and utilizing the `onAuthStateChanged()` methods, but to no avail

Has anyone run into a similar issue? If it's worth noting I'm running on an Ionic v1 platform

Comment: I have the same issue.. Works on Android but not iOS... Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, in my case it was the Dynamic Links defined in XCode. XCode prefixes the dynamic links defined in your config.xml with "applinks". This breaks the redirect when authenticating via Facebook. I need to remove this prefix prior to every deployment to the app store

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that XCode was prefixing all my dynamic links defined in my config.xml with "**applinks**". This prefix breaks the authentication redirect. I have to remove these prefixes prior to every submission to the app store, else OAuth will never successfully work.

Comment: Where do I check if applinks are inserted? config.xml?

Comment: Within XCode, select your project folder, then Build Phases.

Comment: You saved my life :O